# 2 Rows grid, with different item sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, grid-layout

I'm searching for a possibility to create a grid, maybe with a recyclerview, that shows a grid, with two rows, within the items have different heights. 
The width should be the same.

An example is the Google keep app, there are the notices in different sizes.
Here's a screenshot from play store:
[image]

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: see this https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid, it helps me getting the desired view

Comment: `StaggeredGridView` is what you are looking for